# Rename the uploaded file name C#

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload

I have the following C# code:

```
SelectQuery = string.Format("SELECT UserID from tblUsers WHERE Email='{0}'", Email);
ds = DbQ.ExecuteQuery("SiteDB.mdb", SelectQuery);
string UserID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserID"].ToString();
if (Request.ContentLength != 0)
{
    int Size = Request.Files[0].ContentLength / 1024;
    if (Size <= 512)
    {
        string LocalFile = Request.Files[0].FileName;
        int LastIndex = LocalFile.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1;
        File = LocalFile.Substring(LastIndex, LocalFile.Length - LastIndex);
   //     File = "ProfilePic-Id-" + UserID;
        string Path = Server.MapPath("images/profiles/") + File;
        Request.Files[0].SaveAs(Path);

    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("The file is too big !");
    }
}
else
{
    Response.Write("Unknown Error !");
}
```

I want that the uploaded file name rename to "ProfilePic-Id-" + the UserID, I tried in the comment but it didn't work, how can I rename the uploaded file name?

Wish for help, thanks!

Comment: The SQL injection probability...

Comment: `but it didn't work ...` -what **did** happen?

Comment: My email is `'; DROP TABLE tblUsers;`

Comment: The image is not save well, I get some unreconized file and the image does not save at all...

Comment: @BradM, Thanks, I will fix it later...

Comment: @BradM Mine is `' OR '' = '`

Comment: [Rename file in a folder using C#][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680786/rename-files-name-in-a-folder-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
if (Size <= 512)
{
    string path = string.Format("~/images/profiles/ProfilePic-Id-{0}.{1}",
        UserID, System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files[0].FileName));
    Request.Files[0].SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));

}
```

See, when you say `I get some unrecognized file ...`, that's pretty obvious because you don't set an extension on it. The files bytes are likely just fine, it's just an unrecogonized extension by the OS (i.e. it doesn't even have one) and so you need to supply that.

Comment: Thank yuo so much, now I got it!

Comment: @NaveTseva, no problem, I'm glad I could be of assistance!