# Rename file with partly unknown name C#

Tags: c#, .net, file-rename

How do I rename a file using

```
System.IO.File.Move("oldfilename", "newfilename");
```

when I don't know the entire name of the "oldfilename"?

For instance I need to rename two files with the names "2015-10-30 (1) 0001" and "2015-10-30 (1) 0002" and I only want to look for the file that includes "0001" and "0002"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename some files in a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680786/rename-some-files-in-a-folder)

Comment: A directory can be searched for files with a wildcard from the `Directory.GetFiles` method ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)), from there you can choose the relevant full file name and perform the rename.